# 3 activity timer produces null errors

Tags: java, android, android-activity, null

I have 3 activities:

- timer settings that you set the number that the countdown timer starts
- the timer itself
- activated upon pressing the back button

And my problem is that in the pause timer activity(third) when the resume button is pressed the app shows null errors but when the main menu button is pressed the app works fine.

First Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_settings);
    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.numberPicker2);
    np.setMinValue(1);
    np.setMaxValue(999);
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    final Button testbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testbutton);
    testbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent testintent = new Intent(timer_settings.this, timer_2.class);
            Bundle timer2extras = new Bundle();
            timer2extras.putString("timer2string", np.getValue() + "");
            testintent.putExtras(timer2extras);
            startActivity(testintent);
        }
    });
}
```

Second Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_2);
    //...        
    Bundle timer2extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String timer2string = timer2extras.getString("timer2string");
    starttime = Integer.parseInt(timer2string);
    starttimeup = starttime*60000;
    starttimedown = starttime*60000;
    int minutes_up_start = (int) (starttimeup / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds_up_start = (int) (starttimeup / 1000) % 60;
    String time_2_up_start_formatted = 
    String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes_up_start, 
    seconds_up_start);
    timer_2_up.setText(time_2_up_start_formatted);

    int minutes_down_start = (int) (starttimedown / 1000) / 60;
    int seconds_down_start = (int) (starttimedown / 1000) % 60;
    String time_2_down_start_formatted = 
    String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%02d:%02d", minutes_down_start, 
    seconds_down_start);
    timer_2_down.setText(time_2_down_start_formatted);
    //...


@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(timer_2.this, timer_2_pause.class));
}
```

Third Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_2_pause);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    Button main = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button resu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    main.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent mainintent = new Intent(timer_2_pause.this, main_menu.class);
            startActivity(mainintent);
        }
    });
    resu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent resuintent = new Intent(timer_2_pause.this, timer_2.class);
            startActivity(resuintent);
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing onclick for resume :

```
 resu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity two expects to get some data from the intent.

```
Bundle timer2extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String timer2string = timer2extras.getString("timer2string");
```

Your `timer2extras` are null, and when you try to get string from that, it results in null pointer exception.